# Android Button onClickListener() not firing on single click

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am making an android app in which I have a screen whose xml looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btns"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewCalendar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_name_2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
        android:text="View Calendar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createNewMeeting"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_name_2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
        android:text="Add New Meeting"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you can see I have two Buttons `View Calendar` and `Add  New Meeting`. The problem is `View Calendar` button responses on single click while `Add New Meeting` button responses on double click (Note that this happens only when I come into this screen first time after app starts and works fine until the app closed). When app closed and start again then first time again on this screen  this button firing after two taps and so on...

Here is the Java code nothing new just setting `onClickListener` on `Button`

```
    addNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createNewMeeting);

            addNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    // code for add new meeting
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),                 
ActivityReminderNew.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            viewCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewCalendar);

            viewCalendar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    // code for calendar view
                }
            });
```

**R&D:** I have been searching for this problem but mostly I get the answers like to set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` or `android:focusable="true"` in xml but its not solving my problem.

Hope I explained my problem in detail and you guys could understand my issue. Any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a log message inside the click listener of add new meeting button and see if the click listener really doesnt respond or there's a problem with your logic.

Comment: @ShivamVerma Thanks for the suggestion. I put debugger point inside `onClickListener()` its calling on single tap  but not executing the code.

Comment: Well, from all the info you're provided, I think it should work.

Comment: Sorry about the comment I edited it

Comment: I uopdated my code I am calling a new activity on this button click

Comment: If it's calling on single tap, then there's a problem with the logic of your code inside the click listener.

Comment: addNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createNewMeeting); and viewCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewCalendar); should be written in onCreate() method. And OnClickListener() should be imported from View.onClickListener().

Comment: @EagleEye It is in onCreate() method and `onClickListener()` imported from `View.onClickListener()`

Comment: And is this code inside an activity or a fragment ?

Comment: Its inside fragment's onCreateView(). Sorry about that I didn't mentioned this I am using Fragment and buttons used like: `addNew = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addNew);`

Comment: Well, from what I think, this is in a fragment, and you should move the code from inside onCreate to onCreateView();

Comment: Yes you are right but Its inside of onCreateView();

Comment: But you just said in response to @EagleEye that it's inside onCreate(). Anyways, can you just go ahead and put whatever is inside your onCreateView()

Comment: I would check if braces are properly paired. Maybe you _setOnClickListener()_ from inside another one, of from some function...